# Replacing values in a stdClass Object array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been looking for a while and I can't find a way to get this to work. How can I replace values in a stdClass Object array? For example if I have this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 1 
            [fruit] => 100
            [vegetable] => 200
        ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 2
            [fruit] => 100
            [vegetable] => 100
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 3
            [fruit] => 200
            [vegetable] => 200
        ) 
)
```

How do I change the values - fruit 100 to apple, fruit 200 to peach, vegetable 100 to broccoli and vegetable 200 to lettuce - I need to end up with this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 1 
            [fruit] => apple
            [vegetable] => lettuce
        ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 2
            [fruit] => apple
            [vegetable] => broccoli
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 3
            [fruit] => peach
            [vegetable] => lettuce
        ) 
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$fruit = array(
        100 => "apple",
        200 => "peach"
);
$vegetable = array(
        100 => "broccoli",
        200 => "lettuce"
);

$final = array_map(function ($v) use($fruit, $vegetable) {
    $v->fruit = $fruit[$v->fruit];
    $v->vegetable = $fruit[$v->vegetable];
    return $v;
}, $arrayObject);
```

[See live DEMO](http://eval.in/17792)

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I changed `$v->vegetable = $fruit[$v->vegetable];` to `$v->vegetable = $vegetable[$v->vegetable];`

Answer (score 0):

A stdClass Object is not an array, its an object so you need to use object notation:

```
$array[0]->id = 'foo';
```

read here [Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

Answer (score 0):

Lets $array be your array, then:

```
$array[0]->fruit = 'apple';
$array[0]->vegetable = 'lettuce';

$array[1]->fruit = 'apple';
$array[1]->vegetable = 'broccoli';

$array[2]->fruit = 'peach';
$array[2]->vegetable = 'lettuce';
```